# Can I drill a hole in a roof joist where it meets ridge beam?

Tags: beam

Is it structurally safe to drill a small hole approximately 3/4” where roof joists meet to run wire on top of ridge beam for some lights and a fan?  It will look better then tuning the wire along the side of the ridge beam.

[image]

Drill hole (red dots)

[image]

Comment: The proper way to hang electrical wire is to run conduit attached to the ridge beam, or joists, not drilling structural elements at the support point.

Comment: Preferably nice looking wire mould instead of ugly grey Sched 40 PVC or galvanized conduit. Unless, of course, "Industrial" is the look one is going for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can drill a hole 3/4” in diameter vertically through the roof joists where they meet at the ridge.

Drilling a couple of holes vertically through the ridge beam could damage the beam structurally depending on the load and location of the holes. I would not drill in the middle third of the ridge beam without someone (architect or structural engineer) checking it out.

https://images.app.goo.gl/6oE7bGxBMAw3Z2sg7